# RCTEventEmitter payload is null in React Na

Tags: reactjs, objective-c, react-native, appboy, braze

I have the following that emits an event from my iOS app to React Native.

iOS

```
- (void)sendBrazeDeepLinkUrlToReactNative: (NSString *) payload {
  if (hasListeners) {
    [self sendEventWithName:@"incomingRNAppEvent" body:@{@"url":payload}];
  }
}
```

And then I listen for the event in my React Native App.

```
const AppNotificationEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(AppNotification);
      const subscription = AppNotificationEmitter.addListener(
        "incomingRNAppEvent",
        (event: any) => {
          console.log("InAppMessage Recieved: ", JSON.stringify(event));

          console.log("AppNotification: ", event);
        }
      );
```

When the event occurs, I am getting the event triggered and everything works as expected
EXCEPT...

The event object received in React Native contains an empty object???

e.g. the output from `console.log("AppNotification", event) is:

`AppNotification:  {"url": null}`

and I was able to confirm that the URL was definitely set by debugging the iOS native module, and checking the value when the event is triggered. i.e. payload was a valid url.

Comment: Does Android work normally?

Comment: Had not yet implemented a similar behaviour using Android yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out my knowledge of Objective-C was the issue. The object coming into my sendBrazeDeepLinkUrlToReactNative was getting a NSURL * rather than NSString

```
- (void)sendBrazeDeepLinkUrlToReactNative: (NSString *) payload {
  if (hasListeners) {
    [self sendEventWithName:@"incomingRNAppEvent" body:@{@"url":payload}];
  }
}
```

This code works.

```
- (void)sendBrazeDeepLinkUrlToReactNative: (NSURL *) payload {
  if (hasListeners) {
    [self sendEventWithName:@"incomingRNAppEvent" body:@{@"url":payload.absoluteString}];
  }
}
```